# Python 2 + multiprocessing.Pool.map for endless iterable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

The code below (python2) never logs anything, all python processes
started, but no log messages and no records being saved.

**Any clues?**

```
def writer(record):
    log.debug("Writing {}/{}".format(
        threading.currentThread().getName(), record))
    record.save()
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # this is class implementing cycling iterable
    # therefore it never ends
    streamer = simulation.streams.SimulationStreamer(cfg.config)

    p = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
    p.map(writer, streamer)
```

**SimulationStreamer** class implements **iter** and next() methods. 
this is [implementation](https://gist.github.com/dmitry-saritasa/dd385ae2bad93a8cf02c9b480ebf8980) of it

Because it's endless iterable I can't define `__len__` method in the class

Comment: Have you tried `p.imap`?

Comment: yes, when I tried imap - the code just finished  in 1 second with no messages in the log. While when map is called - I get python processing hanging (visible via ps -aufx | grep python) but clearly they use cpu but doing nothing.

If I call code in a single thread - all things are logged, i.e. it.s not about logger being set incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

`Pool.map` [will try to convert the iterable to a list](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e1a44f70b74e19f845086e6b108070a882e58c41/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L304) to find its length. Use `p.imap` instead.

Comment: it quits the execution immediately without any exceptions

Comment: @DmitrySemenov: You have to use the result. `for _ in p.imap(…): pass`

Comment: I got exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create.py", line 46, in <module>
    for x in p.imap(writer, streamer):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 668, in next
    raise value
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed

Comment: @DmitrySemenov: Your records (whatever a `SimulationStreamer` produces during iteration) aren’t serializable, which they have to be in order to be passed between processes.